# java files in different package not compiling

Tags: java

Here is my code

```
package com.a;
public class A{}
```

I compiled using

```
javac -d . A.java
```

I gets compiled in  com/a/A.claas

Now I created another class

```
package com.b;
import com.a.A;
class B extends A{}
```

compiled it with `javac -d . B.java`
and throwing error

```
B.java:2: error: cannot find symbol
import com.a.A;
        ^
symbol:   class A
location: package com.a
B.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
class B extends A{}
              ^
symbol: class A
2 errors
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is checking your code, and since you're only compiling class `B` and not class `A` at the same time, the compiler throws an error because it doesn't know what `A` is. So either compile all your classes at the same time with

```
javac -d . A.java B.java
```

Or tell `javac` where to find class of `A` with the `-classpath` option. The classpath you specify should either be a .jar file that contains `A`, or the base directory of your class structure. I.e. if your class `A` is at `/foo/bar/com/a/A.class`, your classpath would be `/foo/bar/`

```
javac -classpath . -d . B.java
```

Check out [the man page](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/courses/629/jdkdocs/tooldocs/solaris/javac.html) for `javac` as well.